# Эффективный способ получить k последовательных элементов из неотсортированного массива

Tags: c, алгоритм, производительность

Имеется не отсортированный массив А из n элементов. Нужно получить k последовательных элементов массива, начиная с элемента i, из отсортированной версии массива A.

```
Пример:  
На входе:  A {1,6,13,2,8,0,100,3,-4,10}  
           k=3  
           i=4  
На выходе: sublist B {2,3,6}
```

На сегодняшний день решаем следующим образом. Начинаем считывать массив A и строим массив B из i+k элементов. Каждый новый элемент из А сравниваем с последним элементом из B. Если он больше, то движемся дальше, если меньше - то вставляем его в массив B в нужное место. После того, как извлечены все элементы из A, то просто берем k последних элементов из B.

Работает эффективно для небольших значений k и i. Но при больших значениях, скажем k=5 и i=100000 и количестве элементов в A = 1 миллиард, алгоритм расходует много места.

Comment: Соглашусь с @Abyx и немного дополню. Есть такое понятие k-я порядковая статистика, которое означает k-ый по возрастанию элемент в массиве. Есть довольно эффективный алгоритм ее вычисления. Тогда как ваша задача сводится к вычислению нескольких статистик. Кстати алгоритм реализован в STL. Функция называется `nth_element`. Работает он на основе алгоритма "быстрой сортировки"

Comment: Посмотрю более подробно про эти функции. Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии - мимо кассы. Автор вопроса ясно указал, что даже массив размером `i+k` - это слишком большой расход памяти. А алгоритмы STL потребуют произвольного доступа (читай: чтения в память) *всего* исходного массива размера `n`. Т.е. вопрос совершенно не об этом. Вопрос именно о том, как найти `[i, i+k)` по порядку элементы во внешнем массиве данных размера `n`, при условии, что этот размер *слишком велик для прямого чтения массива в память*.

Comment: @Dmitrii Dunaev: А что означает фраза "Имеется не отсортированный массив А из n элементов"? Вы в вопросе жалуетесь на то что массив размера `i+k` потребляет много памяти.  Но в общем случае `n > i+k`, т.е. массив `A` потребляет еще больше памяти. Так где хранится `A`? В памяти или не в памяти? И если в памяти, то разрешается ли модифицировать сам `A`?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем вообще выделять **так много** памяти на временные данные. По сути вам достаточно `2*k` места. Можно дальше оптимизировать, если, скажем, `2*k < K`, где `K` -- максимальный размер буфера, который мы можем себе позволить.